# Suppress weights information from nnet package in rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, gtsummary, nnet

Is it possible to suppress the weights information from the nnet package in rmarkdown? If I set include = FALSE, everything will be hidden. message = FALSE does not appear to work.

````
---
title: "Crimes"
date: "19/11/2021"
output: word_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, message = FALSE)
library(nnet)
library(gtsummary)

set.seed(20211119)

# dummy data
crime <-
  data.frame(
    city = sample(c("SF", "AR", "NYC", "MN"), 13000, replace = TRUE),
    year = sample(as.factor(c(1990, 2000, 1999, 1989)), 13000, replace = TRUE)
  )

```


```{r}
tbl <-
  nnet::multinom(city ~ year, data = crime) %>%
  tbl_regression(exponentiate = TRUE)
tbl

```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want this output?

````
```{r, message = FALSE, echo = FALSE, include = FALSE}
tbl <-
  nnet::multinom(city ~ year, data = crime) %>%
  tbl_regression(exponentiate = TRUE)
```

```{r}
tbl
```
````

[image]

Comment: Yes! I do the modelling seperately in the chunk where output is suppressed then display the object in the chunk where I need it to be display.

Comment: @Moses Good luck in the future work ;)